# Reason I would get 403 rest_forbidden accessing WP API taxonomies/name-of-taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get a list of taxonomies using the WordPress REST API. Hitting `/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/post_tag` works fine, but I also have a custom taxonomy called location and accessing `/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/location` returns a 403 `rest_forbidden` error.

I can't figure out under what circumstances taxonomy REST access would be forbidden in this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set **show_in_rest** to true when registering your taxonomy.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

If your custom taxonomy was created by a plugin and you need to alter it's behaviour try this post :

http://scottbolinger.com/custom-taxonomies-in-the-wp-api/

In short, you can add the code below to your functions file to enable **show_in_rest** for all custom taxonomies.

```
function prefix_add_taxonimies_to_api() {
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false
    ); 
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args, 'objects');
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        $taxonomy->show_in_rest = true;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'prefix_add_taxonimies_to_api', 30);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this, it's exactly what I needed to know.